# Is it possible to send the x and y coordinates of the mouse's current location with a trigger.('mouseup') event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, triggers, click

I'm trying to make a drawing pad that keeps sending the location of the mouse AND registers a "click" every 1 second. I've tried this, but it doesn't seem to be working -

```
$( "#canvas" ).mouseover(function() {
    setInterval(function(){
            var mouseLocation = new jQuery.Event("mouseup");
             var x = mouseLocation.pageX ;
             var y = mouseLocation.pageY ;
            $('#canvas').trigger(mouseLocation);
            console.log('Interval function is working');
            console.log(mouseLocation.pageX);
        },400);
  });
```

the console shows the 'Interval function is working', but it says x is not definted

Comment: I spent 5mn answering to the previous answer that you just deleted, which was 99% same as this one. Please be fair.

Comment: you don't define "x" anywhere. try that first.

Comment: just log mousemove coords and grab the last known ones when needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click events dont have x and y coordinate.
Do grab x and y coordinate you have to attach mousemove or mouseover event to the element.

```
$(function(){
    var canvas = document.getElementsByTagName("canvas")[0];
    var offset = $("canvas").offset();
    var a = document.getElementById("a");
    canvas.addEventListener("mousemove",function(event){
        a.innerText = (event.x - offset.left) + " " + (event.y - offset.top)
    })
})
```

since you want continuous polling of x and y coordinates mousemove is better event to be attached.
fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/BBnuu/